# How to store MKOverlay object to file for retrieving later

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdata, mkoverlay, writetofile

I am writing an iOS application to record your travel path and then storing it so that it can be retrieved later. Most of the code for drawing the path is based on the sample code [Breadcrumb](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html).

Now I am adding features to save the drawn overlay. What is best way to do it? I can use `CoreData` but I am not looking to do much to the drawn overlay rather than retrieving it later again. I have currently tried a simple `NSArray`. I convert the CrumbPath object into `NSData` and store it in the array. Later I retrieve it and convert it back to CrumbPath. However, I seem to be doing something wrong.

```
@interface CrumbPath : NSObject <MKOverlay>
{
    MKMapPoint *points;
    NSUInteger pointCount;
    NSUInteger pointSpace;

    MKMapRect boundingMapRect;

    pthread_rwlock_t rwLock;
}

- (id)initWithCenterCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord;
- (MKMapRect)addCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord;

@property (readonly) MKMapPoint *points;
@property (readonly) NSUInteger pointCount;

@end
```

I save a CrumbPath object "crumbs" like this:

```
NSData *pointData = [NSData dataWithBytes:crumbs.points length:crumbs.pointCount * sizeof(MKMapPoint)];
[patternArray addObject:pointData];
[timeArray addObject:date];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// Create the full file path by appending the desired file name
NSString *patternFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"patterns.dat"];
NSString *timeFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"times.dat"];

//Save the array
[patternArray writeToFile:patternFile atomically:YES];
[timeArray writeToFile:timeFile atomically:YES];
```

And retrieve it later like this to show in a table:

```
NSData *pointData = [appDelegate.patternArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
MKMapPoint *points = malloc(pointData.length);
(void)memcpy([pointData bytes], points, sizeof(pointData));
```

And construct the path again:

```
crumbs = [[CrumbPath alloc] initWithCenterCoordinate:MKCoordinateForMapPoint(points[0])];
for (int i = 1; i <= pointCount; i++) {
    [crumbs addCoordinate:MKCoordinateForMapPoint(points[i])];
}    
[map addOverlay:crumbs];
```

However, I get an error: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteData isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Unrelated to your exception, you're showing us your calls to `malloc`, but not the corresponding `free` calls. I assume you have that somewhere, but make sure you clean up after yourself. Or you can avoid calls to `malloc` and `memcpy` (like my code sample below) and you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd be inclined to do it as follows:

1. First, I'd be inclined to save the C array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` coordinates that I pass to `MKPolygon` instance method `polygonWithCoordinates` (rather than a `MKMapPoint` C array). You can adapt this code if you'd rather use `MKMapPoints`, but I prefer a format which I can examine externally and make sense of (namely the latitude and longitude values of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`). So, let's assume that you make your `MKPolygon` with a line of code like so:

   ```
   MKPolygon* poly = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coordinates count:count];
   ```

   You could, therefore save the coordinates like so:

   ```
   [self writeCoordinates:coordinates count:count file:filename];
   ```

   Where `writeCoordinates:count:filename:` is defined as follows:

   ```
   - (void)writeCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)coordinates count:(NSUInteger)count file:(NSString *)filename
   {
       NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:coordinates length:count * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)];
       [data writeToFile:filename atomically:NO];
   }
   ```

   You could then make the `MKPolygon` from the file with:

   ```
   MKPolygon* poly = [self polygonWithContentsOfFile:filename];
   ```

   where `polygonWithContentsOfFile` is defined as:

   ```
   - (MKPolygon *)polygonWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)filename
   {
       NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
       NSUInteger count = data.length / sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D);
       CLLocationCoordinate2D *coordinates = (CLLocationCoordinate2D *)data.bytes;

       return [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coordinates count:count];
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively, you could read and write the array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` in a plist format (which renders it in a human readable format), by replacing the two above methods with:

   ```
   const NSString *kLatitudeKey = @"latitude";
   const NSString *kLongitudeKey = @"longitude";

   - (void)writeCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)coordinates count:(NSUInteger)count file:(NSString *)filename
   {
       NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];

       for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
           CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = coordinates[i];
           [array addObject:@{kLatitudeKey:@(coordinate.latitude), kLongitudeKey:@(coordinate.longitude)}];
       }

       [array writeToFile:filename atomically:NO];
   }

   - (MKPolygon *)polygonWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)filename
   {        
       NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filename];
       NSUInteger count = [array count];
       CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[count];

       for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
           NSDictionary *dictionary = array[i];
           coordinates[i].latitude = [dictionary[kLatitudeKey] doubleValue];
           coordinates[i].longitude = [dictionary[kLongitudeKey] doubleValue];
       }

       return [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coordinates count:count];
   }
   ```

Clearly you'd want to add error checking code to make sure that the `writeToFile` and the `dataWithContentsOfFile` (or `arrayWithContentsOfFile`) succeeded, but hopefully this gives you the idea.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I shall try out these two methods. However, do you have any idea why I am getting that error.

Comment: @Sap I suspect that this error is not from the code in your question, but rather somewhere that you're calling `isEqualToString` but the object in question is a `NSData`, not a `NSString`. I'd suggest searching for occurrences of `isEqualToString` in your code. Bottom line, you really have to identify the precise line of code that is generating that exception. You can either single-step through your code or add an [exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) to identify the offending code.

Comment: I initially tried to modify your code for MKMapPoints. I was still having trouble storing the file. However, I gave up and stored coordinates as you suggested. It works. Thanks!